# Welcome Email takes about 5 minutes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, email-templates

I have a problem with my Magento website.
The sending of transactional emails always delay and take about 5 minutes.
Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: Could you show us your crontab? You can do so with `crontab -l`. Furthermore please consider that once the email is sent from your server the further processing can take time.

Comment: odd, because the only emails sent from cron are the order confirmation emails.. @codedge

Comment: One reason I am thinking of is that the Magento cron.sh is running each 5 minutes. That means the email queue can take up to 5 min before an email is being processed and sent. What Magento versionsre you using?

Comment: depends on your cron and email gateway configuration